# Multiple $inc updates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to update a single document by passing two $inc operators in a single update document?

For example, I am trying to increment two different fields in a given document using the following update document:

```
{
    "$inc" : { "ViewAggregates.4d75b891842f2d3930cf7674" : 1 },
    "$inc" : { "ViewAggregates.Total" : 1 }
}
```

No errors are thrown and the document is updated but only one of the fields has been incremented.  It is as if the server disregarded the first $inc operator and only the second was actually applied.

Is this the intended\correct behavior or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is an interesting side-effect of dictionary keys being unique -- the second `$inc` overwrites the first.

However, it's still possible to increment more than one field:

```
{
    "$inc": {
        "ViewAggregates.4d75b891842f2d3930cf7674" : 1, 
        "ViewAggregates.Total" : 1
    }
}
```

This works for many other operators too :-)

Comment: Ah! How silly of me to overlook the fact that keys are unique.  Gotta learn not to work so late at night.  Thanks!